# Image is only displayed when height and width are fixed values

Tags: typescript, react-native

This is the most frustrating thing ever. When I set the image width and height to '100%' via the image style property, the image doesn't show up:
[image]

However, when I set it to a fixed value:
[image]

Here's my render():

```
 render() {
    const { images } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {images.map((image, index) => (
          <Animated.Image
            {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
            key={index}
            source={{ uri:`${encodeURI(image)}` }}
            style={[
              styles.image,
              // {
              //   transform: [{ translateX: this.pan.x }],
              //   zIndex: index === this.state.currentIndex ? 1 : 0,
              // },
            ]}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's probably because the parent element has no width / height. So 100% is still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `width` and `height` of image to `100%`, it means image have same `width` and `height` as its parent component.

In your case, you didn't set size to the parent component, so the image has `width` and `height` equal to 0

Comment: My parent is set to flex: 1. Shouldn't that fill the available area? It seems as if the flex:1 is preventing me from setting any width and height. When I remove the flex: 1, it works but it's not convenient as I need the image to fill the whole parent view container.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `width` and `height` of parent `view` to `'100%'` instead of `flex: 1` or just add another view inside of parent with `flex: 1` with `height`, `width` of `'100%'`

EX.

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
        {images.map((image, index) => (
          <Animated.Image
            {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
            key={index}
            source={{ uri:`${encodeURI(image)}` }}
            style={[
              styles.image,
              // {
              //   transform: [{ translateX: this.pan.x }],
              //   zIndex: index === this.state.currentIndex ? 1 : 0,
              // },
            ]}
          />
        ))}
    </View>
</View>
```